# Ubuntu Monitor Configuration

Tags: multiple-monitors

I am trying to automate some functions when a monitor is plugged in or or unplugged.  I am using Ubuntu 15.04.  How can I detect when the monitor changes? Is it possible to execute a shell script when an external monitor is plugged/unplugged in?

Comment: The *question* in the linked dupe only mentions *connecting*. The answer however covers both connecting/disconnecting. On the edge of a literal dupe, but I think it is justified in this case. Leave a comment if you disagree, I'll be happy to elaborate the answer here :).

Comment: Thanks for mentioning. If anything is unclear, please leave a comment.